# Set another page.tpl.php if a parameter is set

Tags: theming, 7

i want to use another page.tpl.php file, if die fb parameter is set.
The File is located in my theme folder and has the name "page-fb.tpl.php"

My Function in template.php

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
/** Facebook Output */
    if ( isset($_GET['fb']) && $_GET['fb'] == 1 ) {
        $vars['template_file'][] = 'page-fb';
    }
}
```

The function is called, but the new page-fb.tpl.php is not loaded.
I'm doing all of this on Drupal 7.

Any advices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename `page-fb.tpl.php` to `page--fb.tpl.php` and then modify your code to use `$vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__fb';` instead of what you got currently. For further information you can check out the [Drupal 7 Template Suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1089656) page.

Answer (score 1):

Here you made a mistake!

```
$vars['template_file'][] = 'page-fb';
```

The above line should be like below.

```
$vars['template_files'][] = 'page-fb';
```

Comment: okay, but is not working either.
i think i forgot to mention, it is on drupal 7.